# Multi directional scrolling on 1 page with animations

Tags: jquery, css, animation, horizontal-scrolling

I'm building this site for a client that basically wants their own version of this:
http://graphicnovel-hybrid4.peugeot.com/start.html

Ideally, I would like to use superscrollorama (http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/) but I can't figure out how to switch to horizontal scrolling in the middle of the page. I tried using waypoints (http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#about) to change the direction, which worked but the animations stopped working in the horizontal section.

Also, it needs to be responsive and work on a tablet. Not looking for the work to be done for me but mainly wondering if anyone has any ideas or any experience with something like this or if there is some magical plugin that does all or some of these things.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered using two distinct superscrollorama instances?

Comment: Yes, I tried declaring two different controllers but that didn't work, it basically just uses whichever one is declared second.

Comment: Superscrollorama didnt support multiple instances. ScrollMagic does. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe it but there actually is a magical plugin that does everything I need!! http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/ . I contacted John Polacek, the creator of scollorama and he sent me a link to a colleague's plugin.